# PHP session time out on browser open

Tags: php, session, timeout

I know there are many threads regarding PHP sessions while ajax queries etc...
but my problem is,

I have an ajax grid (build after the page load), which I allow to edit only when use is logged on. I don't mind for session to be not checked until user actually change the page (then `valid_session.php` is called),
but I have an issue, when next day user opens the browser on the same page - the grid is still editable! obviously if I refresh the page, then user get logged out.

I have no-cache set on my pages, but browsers (in particular chrome) don't reload it on open.

I can't get my head around as how to force it to refresh on reopen. please guide me to the right direction...

---

EDIT

BTW - I found a way to handle this. I simply call `session_destroy();` in `session_destroy.php` on `unload()` via `$.get()`:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.get('session_destroy.php', function(data) {
      alert(data); // alerts me of some var set to 0 - meaning session is destroyed.
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say the user opens the browser on the same page, how is this achieved? Is it a bookmark? A default home page? A pinned tab?

Comment: u know u can set - reopen with the same tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set a "last refreshed" cookie, and have a javascript `setInterval()` which checks if the cookie is older than, say 20 minutes. If it is, the javascript triggers a refresh. Of course, you still need to log them out after the inactivity period.

Comment: but that would mean that user may loose all unsaved changes, right?

Comment: @Elen You can tell user that session has expired and unsaved changes are lost that will be polite way and user won't feel too much discomfort.

Comment: If they close their browser or haven't changed anything for 20 minutes, they probably haven't got any unsaved work to lose. You could also have the `setInterval()` reset the "last refreshed" cookie to the current time, meaning it would only timeout if they have the browser closed for 20 minutes.

Comment: ok understood... i either have to use `$.get()` prior loading the grid to check session, or use `setInterval()` for checking js cookie...

Comment: @Elen It's your choice. I'd check for cookies.

Answer (score 2):

To log out the user actively i think you should do some kind of polling and then trigger a logout automatically when the session expire. Or print an error message like "Changes done to this page will not be saved as the session has expired". 
Obviously the grid can't now "By magic" that the session has expired, you have to tell it somehow. In any case even if the grid it's still editable, it shoul dbe impossible to save changes, otherwise there is a design flaw (like not checking if the user is logged in before saving)

Comment: but that is my point - i don't mind for grid stay editable while the window is open. but once it's closed - on open i would like it reloaded so it's not editable. or - are you saying that it's impossible and that i have to log out user prior?